# error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final Android Java

Tags: java, android, boolean

I want to create an API method that works to check whether the user already exists or not that can be called from all over the place.
I want this method to return a boolean value, true/false. My code is like this:

```
public boolean isUserExistBool(String type, String username, Context context) {
    boolean val = true;

    final ProgressDialog dialog = Functions.showProgressDialog(context, context.getString(R.string.please_wait), context.getString(R.string.please_wait));
    dialog.show();

    RestApi restApi = RetroFit.getInstanceRetrofit();
    Call<SignIn> responseCall = restApi.getUserData(
            type,
            username
    );

    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<SignIn>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<id.wifi.myapp.model.SignIn> call, Response<SignIn> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String result = response.body().getResult();
                String msg = response.body().getMsg();
                User user = response.body().getUser();

                if (result.equals("1")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_user_exist), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    val = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OK you're new", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    val = false;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_msg) + " (" + Functions.networkError(response.code(), response.message()) + ")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                val = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<id.wifi.myapp.model.SignIn> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_msg2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            val = false;
        }
    });

    return val;
}
```

But I'm getting an error warning because of my boolean declaration (`boolean val = true;`) like this

> error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or
> effectively final. val = true;

I tried to replace even though I know it won't work `boolean val = true;` into `final boolean val = true;`, but I get another error

> error: cannot assign a value to final variable val. val = true;

However if I try to solve this with IDE auto correct (`ALT + Enter`), then `val = true;` becomes `val[0] = true;`, as well as other values.

How can I return true/false on every successful/failed process in this method?

Comment: there's a fundamental flaw in your code regardless. trying to use `return val;` will just fail, because it's not a synchronous operation, so your method will always just return true at the moment

Comment: ok, so is there any other alternative?
I can use this method one by one in each activity, but it seems less efficient

Comment: you can make use of callbacks, look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value